# Boostrap / Grid System / CSS Workaround

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, box

Is there a way to do this kind of box/image positioning through Bootstrap 3 Grid system? If not, how do you suppose to code this in plain CSS?

Please click link for picture reference:
[Box Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCyob.jpg)

How someone can help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We are going to help you with what you built, not going to build for you !

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by `Bootstrap Grid System`. I think this code will help you. I have done it for whole screen, you can use it for some section for your screen.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">

      <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">

      <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>

       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">

      <p>Some text..</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) for your clarification about `Grid System` and See some example [Bootstrap Template](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp). I think these will help you.